# mongoDB $concat string with array item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6332dda58121948311cbdb67"
    },
    "date": "2022-09-13",
    "file": "xxx",
    "package": 1,
    "userList": [
      {
        "userName": "user_1",
        "crDate": "2022.09.28",
        "boolId": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6332dda58121948311cbdb68"
    },
    "date": "2022-09-13",
    "file": "xxx",
    "package": 2,
    "userList": []
  }
]
```

My desired output would be this (if all of the `userList` array is empty):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2022-09-13",
    "items": [
      {
        "fileName": "xxx",
        "items": [
          {
            "package": "1 - na" 
          },
          {
            "package": "2 - na" 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this if I would have an object inside the `userList` array:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2022-09-13",
    "items": [
      {
        "fileName": "xxx",
        "items": [
          {
            "package": "1 - user_1" 
          },
          {
            "package": "2 - na" 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I try to run this aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "date": "$date",
        "file": "$file",
        
      },
      "items": {
        $push: {
          "package": {
            $concat: [
              {
                $toString: "package"
              },
              " - ",
              {
                $toString: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$userList",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      "items": {
        $push: {
          "fileName": "$_id.file",
          "items": "$items"
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

It's running if the `userList` array is empty, but it's not returning the desired output and if the `userList` array is not empty it throws this error:

```
Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 241 (ConversionFailure): 'Unsupported conversion from object to string in $convert with no onError value' on server
```

Here comes an example: [mongo_playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OFwZbFDvJrr)

How should I modify the aggregate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires 2 fixes in the first `$group` stage,

- missed the `$` sign in `package` property name, in  `{ $toString: "$package" }`
- use property name `userName` while accessing first element in `$userList.userName`
- use `$ifNull` operator to check if the property is not present then it returns "na" string

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "date": "$date",
        "file": "$file"
      },
      "items": {
        $push: {
          "package": {
            $concat: [
              { $toString: "$package" }, // <====== here 
              " - ",
              {
                $toString: {
                  $ifNull: [
                    { $arrayElemAt: ["$userList.userName", 0] },  // <====== here 
                    "na"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      "items": {
        $push: {
          "fileName": "$_id.file",
          "items": "$items"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/be8DlG0SXXw)